# Unit test throwing default admin username not available error

Tags: java, mockito, alfresco

I am using alfresco 6. In one of the methods I want to test, has the following code:

```
if(AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser().equals("xyz"))
{
        return;
}
```

I want to force this condition to be false while I am doing this unit test.

In the unit tests I have a `@Before` which has the following :

```
AuthenticationUtil.setAdminUserAsFullyAuthenticatedUser();
```

In the actual test I do not have any code related to `AuthenticationUtil`.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AuthenticationUtil not yet initialised; default admin username not available
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.getAdminUserName(AuthenticationUtil.java:450)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `AuthenticationUtil.setAdminUserAsFullyAuthenticatedUser();` method.

It most likely runs the `AuthenticationUtil.getAdminUserName()` method, which is on line 450 of the `AuthenticationUtil` class, and which seems to need a username of admin.

Comment: AuthenticationUtil is a static class in Alfresco and It's not possible to call a setter from the test

Comment: If you check the sourcecode of [`AuthenticationUtil`](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-data-model/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/authentication/AuthenticationUtil.java) you can see that that the method depends on an `initialized` flag, which apparently is related to the `InitializingBean` interface from spring. This [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-initializingbean-and-disposablebean-example/) should show you, how you can configure the `defaultAdminUserName`,